# Regarding macros

Tags: c, macros

i was looking for macro which can expand like the following:

FILL_BUFF(4) should be expanded as (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)... what can be the macro written for the above expansion..

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to do exactly what you want.

Comment: What are you going to do with that parenthesized list?  As a value, it is equivalent to writing (0xFF); as an argument list ... what are you doing with it, exactly?

Comment: @Jonathan: presumably @inquisitive means `{0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF}`

Comment: actually i will be using it in x-macro, something like
x(0x04, {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF}) should be handled using 
x(0x04, FILL_BUFF(0x04))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PP got it - almost.
Abusing the C preprocessor again. On the other hand, it deserves nothing better.

```
#define FILL_BUFF(N) FILL_BUFF_ ## N

#define FILL_BUFF_1 (0xFF)
#define FILL_BUFF_2 (0xFF,0xFF)
#define FILL_BUFF_3 (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF)
#define FILL_BUFF_4 (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF)
```

Comment: @drhirsch: even in thought the same. but i cant keep having so much expansions (it might need till 0 to 63)!

Comment: 0..63 isn't a big set for a header file. I'd only worry about it if the list was more than 1,000 or 10,000 lines long..

Answer (score 2):

Macros don't have conditional controls such as loops - they are very simple.

It's common to see a group of macros in a header covering all the common expansions, e.g.

```
#define FILL_BUFF_1 (0xFF)
#define FILL_BUFF_2 (0xFF,0xFF)
#define FILL_BUFF_3 (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF)
#define FILL_BUFF_4 (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF)
```

Comment: If you REALLY wanted to use the FILL_BUFF(4), you could always have `#define FILL_BUFF(n) FILL_BUFF_##n` to reference back to the ones defined here.  I must emphasise that I'm not recommending this though (apart from anything else, it breaks MISRA rule 19.13 and breaking MISRA rules is almost always a BAD thing in my opinion).

Comment: But i want to have above situation but using macros

Comment: @inquisitive: You can't always get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the [boost preprocessor library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html). Especially the `BOOST_PP_REPEAT_z` macros:

```
#define DECL(z, n, text) text ## n = n;

BOOST_PP_REPEAT(5, DECL, int x)
```

results in:

```
int x0 = 0; int x1 = 1; int x2 = 2; int x3 = 3; int x4 = 4;
```

In your case you could do:

```
#define FILL_BUFF_VALUE(z, n, text) text,
#define FILL_BUFF(NPLUSONE, VALUE) { BOOST_PP_REPEAT(NPLUSONE, FILL_BUFF_VALUE, VALUE } VALUE )

int anbuffer[] = FILL_BUFF(4 /* +1 */,0xff); // anbuffer will have length 5 afterwards
```

which would expand to

```
int anbuffer[] = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };
```

Comment: This is buggy. Currently it expands to "( BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1_4-1(FILL_BUFF_VALUE, 0xff) 0xff )"

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It works now but is a bit ugly unless there is a way to have "N-1" evaluate first inside the macros.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, maybe via memset:

```
#define FILL_BUFF(buf, n) memset(buff, 0xff, n)
```

But I am not sure that is such a good idea

Comment: @laura: I think that should be memset(buf, 0xff, n); you added an extra f into the word in the macro! :)